# How to use row as a column in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

[image]

This is my result I want to get first check in and last Check Out from this result I want to Output Like this

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
atteDate  | staffName      |  staffId | shiftName|firmId| CheckIn |CheckOut | Total Duration
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-20|Swapnil R Gupta |5036      |General   | 1    |09:09:41 |21:33:01 |12:24:01
```

Comment: Sorry but I m not getting properly. means You want to my Current Query

Comment: see the link referenced to know on  how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a conditonal aggregation query, grouping by the date of `attendDate`.

```
select 
    attendDate = convert(date,t.AttendDate)
  , t.staffName
  , t.staffId
  , t.shiftName
  , t.Firmid
  , CheckIn  = min(case when inoutmode = 'checkin'  then convert(time(0),t.AttendDate) end)
  , CheckOut = max(case when inoutmode = 'checkout' then convert(time(0),t.AttendDate) end)
from t
group by 
    t.staffName
  , t.staffId
  , t.ShiftName
  , t.Firmid
  , convert(date,t.attendDate)
```

Comment: But Some where in my Result Only Check In time not check out or some where checkOut time not check in time so how can i manage it?

Comment: @MaheshGawhane Updated to use conditional aggregation to guarantee that the checkin is from a checkin `inoutmode`, and the same for checkout

Comment: can you give me query please?

Comment: @MaheshGawhane Updated my answer, refresh the page.

Comment: One more condition is not satisfy in this scenario. That is  if my shift time is start at 18:00:00 and shift end time is 03:00:00 so in that case how can i manage it?

Comment: Can you give me reply plz for above comment

Comment: Can you help me. I want Total duration between Checkin and checkOut Time How can I manage It?

Comment: @MaheshGawhane That's a different question, post it as a new question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query it gives the required output :

```
DECLARE @EMPLOYEEDATA TABLE(ATTENDDATE DATETIME,STAFFNAME VARCHAR(100),STAFFID INT, SHIFTNAME VARCHAR(100),FIRMID INT,ATTENDID INT,INOUTMODE VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @EMPLOYEEDATA VALUES
('2017-03-20 09:09:41.000','SRG',5036,'GENERAL',1,34173,'CHECKIN'),
('2017-03-20 13:01:11.000','SRG',5036,'GENERAL',1,34217,'CHECKOUT'),
('2017-03-20 17:47:10.000','SRG',5036,'GENERAL',1,34218,'CHECKOUT'),
('2017-03-20 19:34:27.000','SRG',5036,'GENERAL',1,34226,'CHECKOUT'),
('2017-03-20 21:33:01.000','SRG',5036,'GENERAL',1,34227,'CHECKOUT')

SELECT     CONVERT(VARCHAR,CHECKIN,105)ATTENDATE,STAFFNAME,STAFFID,SHIFTNAME,CAST(CHECKIN     AS TIME) CHECKIN,CAST(CHECKOUT AS TIME)CHECKOUT FROM(
SELECT     STAFFNAME,STAFFID,SHIFTNAME,MIN(ATTENDDATE)CHECKIN,MAX(ATTENDDATE)CHECKOUT FROM     @EMPLOYEEDATA GROUP BY STAFFNAME,STAFFID,SHIFTNAME)DATA
```

**OUTPUT**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--ATTENDATE STAFFNAME   STAFFID SHIFTNAME   CHECKIN CHECKOUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
20-03-2017  SRG 5036    GENERAL 09:09:41.0000000    21:33:01.0000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```